# Mybatis - nested lazy loaded result property is already exist on result map issue

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql, mybatis-plus

I’m plan to upgrade the spring from 4 to 5
Due to which I need to upgrade  mybatis from 2 to 3.5.11

While upgrading mybatis , I’m facing this issue which is something unclear to me.

I’m getting below error-

```
 nested exception is org.apache ibatis:executor ExecutorException:
 Nested lazy loaded result property "xyz” for  “com.xyz.ApplicationMybatisDaogetbyName” already exists in the result  map. The leftmost property of al lazy loaded properties must be unique within a result map.
```

But I checked in my mybatisDao xml , only once it’s mentioned:

Same thing was working in older version of mybatis.

This issue is occurring on using associations it seems but not sure.

I used association as:

property:  xyz , column: column name
,  select: com.xyz.ApplicationMybatisDaogetbyName

I tried to add the properties of sql session bean -

```
configuration.setLazyLoadingEnabled(false); configuration.setAggressiveLazyLoading(false); configuration.setReturnInstanceForEmptyRow(true);
```

But it didn’t worked.

Any lead to avoid this issue would be appreciated

Comment: We basically need information to reproduce the same problem on our end. Could you provide a small project that reproduces the problem? [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some project templates and examples. Please do not include mybatis-plus (if it's a MyBatis problem, it should be reproduced without mybatis-plus).